# Does jdbcRealm use cache? (Glassfish server)

Tags: caching, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jdbcrealm

Does `com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm` use caching?

Let me describe my situation.
When I use file realm on my application, everything works Ok, but when I try to use remote DB I have strange behavior. Actually authentication works well, but client app start throwing exceptions.

My application frequently (every 200 ms) send requests to Glasswish appserver via JAX-RS.

So I suppose that realm does not manage to finish before the other starts. And if I'm right, then caching can solve my problem, but I cannot fint that options in glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exam JDBCrealm code from http://kickjava.com/src/com/sun/enterprise/security/auth/realm/jdbc/JDBCRealm.java.htm

It caches only groups. To cache users I use this lib: http://flexiblejdbcrealm.wamblee.org/site/